# Getting invalid_request - Token type is not allowed. error while accessing Lists and list Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, splistitem

I am trying to get SharePoint list and its items by REST API. Below is the approach I have done -

Create a App in SharePoint. Got the Client ID, Client Secret. Using the below URL I got the access token

> [https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{TenanatId}/tokens/OAuth/2](https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/%7BTenanatId%7D/tokens/OAuth/2)

Now I am using the below URL to get List Items -

> [https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/myname/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylistname')/items](https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/myname/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27mylistname%27)/items)

Method - GET
In Header I provided the below details
Authorization : Bearer + Access Token
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose

I am getting

> 401 Unauthoried -
> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token type is not
> allowed."}

Below permission i have given in the APP Permission XML

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl"/>
    </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the command `set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false`.

Here is a similar issue for your reference:

[SharePoint Online authorization issue 'Token type is not allowed'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284402/sharepoint-online-authorization-issue-token-type-is-not-allowed)